# how to know if a client is alive or not

Tags: c#, client-server

i have a client-server app and i wish to know how can i find out if my client is alive or not ? I was thinking of sending a package from my client especially for this every (lets say) 1 minute and if my server doesn't receive notice of that package in 1 minute, it closes that client connection .

I also saw (both client and server are locally for this test ) that if a client is connected to the server and i end that process ( via task manager ) my server breaks for that connection (actually it is surrounded by a try catch so it closes the connection after that ) . Can i use this  ? how often does the server check the stream to see if the client is connected ?

Comment: I think you will get better answers if you share some details on how the client and server are connected, and perhaps also why the connection needs to be alive.

Comment: Depends on what does the server need it for.

Comment: i collect some data on the client from a micro-controller and send it to the server . The connection is made with TcpClient . The server waits for the client to send data and displays is. The max number of clients is 200 and the OS is x86 probably winXP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing any detail on your system's architecture and number of clients, it is usually not recommended for server to contact client for various reasons (Firewall, security, ...) so this is normally achieved by a "heartbeat" from the client.

Comment: both client and server will run on windows x86 probably XP and the number of clients is max 200..